# NHibernate Projections - How to project a value from within associations

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to project a single value from an entity's association with no luck. Only want the **city name** from the TrainerAddress in the query below. Trainer address is mapped as a component of Trainer.

```
session.QueryOver<Trainer>()
   .JoinAlias(x=>x.TrainerAddress.City, ()=> cityAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
   .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc
   .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.Id)
        .Select(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
        .Select(x => x.TrainerAddress.City.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.City))//issue projecting here
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TrainerDTO>())
  .List<TrainerDTO>();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems possible. What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying an alias for TrainerAddress.City but you don't use that alias anywhere?
I'm not 100% sure if NHibernate supports components well in QueryOver, I know there were some issues with it using Criteria, but maybe this will work:

```
session.QueryOver<Trainer>()
   .JoinAlias(x=> x.TrainerAddress.City, ()=> cityAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
   .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc
   .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.Id)
        .Select(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
        .Select(x => cityAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.City))
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TrainerDTO>())
  .List<TrainerDTO>();
```

Comment: Nice one Martin. I specify the join to eager load. Seems the using the alias did the trick and can't seem to navigate using x.TrainerAddress.City.Name

Comment: Glad to know it worked - guess they've improved the support for components :)